# Pressing enter key doesn't search

Tags: php, jquery

Searching event isn't triggered with enter key but works fine if manually press Search button.
Here's my simple script

```
$('#searchproductbrand').live('click',function() {
    var search = $('.searchproductbrand').val();
    window.open('search.php?search='+search,'_self');
});

$('.searchproductbrand').keypress(function(e) {
if (e.which == 13) {
var search = $('.searchproductbrand').val();
window.open('search.php?search='+search,'_self');
}
});
```

And here is my textbox & button.

```
<input type="search" id="text" class="searchproductbrand" placeholder="Search for Product, Brand" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)" autofocus="autofocus" />
<input type="button" id="searchproductbrand" class="button" value="Search" style="padding: 10px 10px;"/>
```

So pressing button works fine but pressing enter key while searching doesn't work. Anyone can help?

Comment: It's more easy to let the key press trigger a click on the search button. That will fix your problem I guess.

Comment: Yes that could be another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried  live("keypress") ?

Comment: Yes that worked, adding live to the code worked fine. But can you tell me why it worked & why the above code didn't?

Comment: @shanil Probably the elment you were attempting to keypress was loaded dynamically and therefore unable to catch the keypress event

Comment: Oh yes, that could be possible. Thanks anyway.:)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.searchproductbrnad')   is it brand or brnad? typo?
```

Answer (score 1):

pressing enter submits a form, so just make it a proper form...

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
//do stuff
return false;
}

</script>


<form onsubmit="return myFunction();">
<input type="search" id="text" class="searchproductbrand" placeholder="Search for Product, Brand" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)" autofocus="autofocus" />
<input type="submit" id="searchproductbrand" class="button" value="Search" style="padding: 10px 10px;"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Creating form was not needed, so wanted to do it without using the form. By the way added 'live('keypress',function(e)' this & it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the `document` object.

Change your `keypress` code like this

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    var search = $('.searchproductbrand').val();
    window.open('search.php?search='+search,'_self');
  }
});
```

I hope, it will solve your issue.

Comment: This will make the form submit by pressing the enter button anywhere in the document. That is usually not wanted.

Comment: @Veda You are right. But I just gave the solution, He should add the checks like if there is focus on input field, or submit the form on condition. you know what I mean.

Comment: Adding this 'live('keypress',function(e)' worked fine for me, by the way thanks so much for your suggestion.